# Phpminiadmin access denied for user@root(0)

Tags: php-7, magento2.1.0

I am installing Magento-2.1.0 and for this need database.

I have added phpminiadmin on root, now accessing with the correct username and password still showing error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Magento related question and should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

I think you  are not updating database details in app/etc/env.php file.
First update here your loin details, delete var folder create ones again var folder, I hope it will be helpful for you.